# How to push submodule to github using android studio?

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I cloned an android project from github. I made changes after cloning and pushed it to the main repository from android studio. Everything worked fine but when I add an external library in my project I can't push it. I think its a sub module. Could anyone tell me how to push external library as a sub module from android studio?

Comment: I have found that git integration on eclipse is poor. I recommend using something like [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree) or even the [git command line](http://git-scm.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a submodule, you should be able to list the [gitlink entry, special mode 160000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD mysubmodule 
 160000 commit c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398  mysubmodule
```

It should also be recorded in your `main repo/.gitmodules` file.

In that case, all you need to do is add and commit that entry, and push it.

If it is not, then remove that folder, and add it again as a submodule through command-line (instead of Eclipse/Egit)

```
git submodule add /url/of/library/repo mysubmodule
git add mysubmodule   # no trailing / here)
git commit -m "Add a submodule"
git push toAndroidRemoteRepo
```

Answer (score 3):

After searching internet I found a simple way to do it. To add a sub-module we need to run this command

`git submodule add LIBRARY_URL`

and to init the sub module locally

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: +1. That is the idea I was suggesting in my answer: once the submodule is added, it becomes a simple entry in your main repo.